# Galaxy Nexus randomly shut downs while streaming music with Pandora- how do I fix this?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, pandora

While streaming music with the Pandora application (on the high quality setting) on a Galaxy Nexus over Verizon 4G, after any given time period the phone will completely shut down. This happens at unpredictable times. The phone doesn't get heated and no data/download limits are reached. I'm fairly certain this is a bug with the Pandora app on ICS or could be ICS in general, as it is not experienced during any other data streaming.

- Has anyone experienced this random shut down while streaming with Pandora on their device, and if so..
- Is there remedy for this type of bug?

Comment: Do you use bluetooth devices with your phone while using Pandora (whether they directly interact with it or not)?

Comment: @Mr.Buster No bluetooth devices at all.

Answer (score 1):

For random shut downs, that's most probably a loose battery problem.

Stick some dental floss (I used [Oral-B Glide](http://www.oralb.com/products/floss/) floss) in the side opposite the battery connectors.  I used that floss because it's a bit spongy when you bunch it up but at the same time hard.  Used about 1.5 feet of it bundled up in my Nexus S phone.

[image: flossy solution]

When you push the battery in, make sure it is tight, but not too tight.

This will force the battery to remain contacted at the pins.  When the battery is loose and can disconnect from the pins (for even a fraction of a second), you get an open circuit and the phone shuts off completely (no power).